# I rotate a dodecahedron around a axis through its opposite edges

Tags: geometry

Which faces are fixed? I believe that 2 pairs of opposite faces should be fixed.

I know that rotating around the axis through middle opposite faces only fixes 1 pair of faces.

Please help me visualize or create a diagram to show which faces are fixed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you visualize the rotation (click on it):

[image: rotating dodecahedron]

Comment: Using raw data we can join vertices to get edges which can be rotated at  about 30 intervals around the axis to get more idea..

Answer (score 0):

Annular rings at top and bottom faces between top face in-circle and circum-circle.

In addition several hyperboloids of one sheet with both the rulings made by skewed edges of dodecahedron as generators.

The following raw data of vertices (Mma) could be useful:

-1.37638,0.,0.262866
1.37638,0.,-0.262866
-0.425325,-1.30902,0.262866
-0.425325,1.30902,0.262866
1.11352,-0.809017,0.262866
1.11352,0.809017,0.262866
-0.262866,-0.809017,1.11352
-0.262866,0.809017,1.11352
-0.688191,-0.5,-1.11352
-0.688191,0.5,-1.11352
0.688191,-0.5,1.11352
0.688191,0.5,1.11352
0.850651,0.,-1.11352
-1.11352,-0.809017,-0.262866
-1.11352,0.809017,-0.262866
-0.850651,0.,1.11352
0.262866,-0.809017,-1.11352
0.262866,0.809017,-1.11352
0.425325,-1.30902,-0.262866
0.425325,1.30902,-0.262866